# Hide apache webserver webpage

Tags: apache, svn, https, webserver, hide

Probably a very basic problem: I have a SVN server hosted via Apache with a public IP address and I want to prevent it from displaying the SVN server contents in the browser via it's URL.

By default anyone who can guess the IP address and URL can see and download the contents of my SVN repo through their browser (the Apache web server generates a default website). How can I prevent this? I would still like to be able to access my SVN server via HTTPS as an SVN client, but I don't want random people gaining viewing access to my repo through their browser.

I'm on Debian 10 with the latest supported SVN (hosted on a `f1-micro` Google Cloud Compute Engine). Hosting is provided via the Apache module `dav_svn` with OpenSSL to upgrade to HTTPS.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not much information about your installation and OS. Blind guess would be uninstalling websvn. Is that the SVN webbrowser component you are using?

Comment: Sorry for leaving that info out! I've updated my question to reflect this. I'm not actually sure about websvn. This was basically how it was by default (basically a clean/raw install of apache).